Падает бот на сервере
Через какое-то время бот падает с ошибкой, точнее он падает и перезапускается, но основная логика без команды /start не продолжает работать.
Я попробовал обработать данную ошибку с помощью true: except Exception:. Рационально ли использовать данную конструкцию при такой ошибке:
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher:Failed to fetch updates - TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - Request timeout error
WARNING:aiogram.dispatcher:Sleep for 2.248403 seconds and try again... (tryings = 4, bot id = 7378138493)
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher:Connection established (tryings = 5, bot id = 7378138493)


Ну так проблема в сети на сервере либо телеграму плохо. Что за сервер у вас?

Попробуйте перехватывать именно эту ошибку:
from requests import JSONDecodeError
import traceback

try:
  response = requests.get(...)
  json = response.json()
except JSONDecodeError as ex:
  logger.warning(f'Получена ошибка {ex}')
  logger.debug(f'{traceback.format_exc()}')

Если вы получаете json у response попробуйте заменить его на response.text и посмотреть, что вам прилетает, возможно ответ не в формате json.
Может быть банально сетевая проблема и тогда простой перехват ошибки поможет защитить бота от падения.
